# Passing keyword argument if condition is True

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a more pythonic way to do this ?

```
if condition:
    return f(x, y, z=1)
else:
    return f(x, y)
```

Comment: For such a simple piece of code, I wouldn't worry about being "more pythonic". I'd keep it as it is to maintain its readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditionally build your kwargs:

```
kwargs = {}
if condition:
    kwargs['z'] = 1

return f(x, y, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Probably not the best for a single kwarg.

Comment: Sure, you could probably boil it down to something simpler in this specific case, but that's the general approach I'd pursue.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution looks Pythonic enough, although you can flatten it using a ternary conditional:

```
return f(x, y, z=1) if condition else f(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return f(x, y, z=condition)
```

if condition is boolean ;)

Comment: But ``z`` could be a number and we don't know the default value (could be ``-1`` or ``None`` for all we know).

Comment: That is true. The problem is, that this question doesn't provide enough intel about it...